# How to beat the training ground in Ninja Village

Tags: ninja-village

I'm on my first playthrough of Ninja village on android and have finished everything else, except the training grounds. I'm currently stuck on lvl 145 and can't seem to figure out the right hero combination to beat the level. My army is maxed out and the ninjas I'm using are all lvl 30. my formation is as follow:

```
Infantry:
  Edajima    [Horse resist 3]
  Shima      [Melee resist 4] kairo armor
  galapagos  [Bullet resist 4]
  Asaruy     [strategy 4]
Archers 
  Oda        [strategy 3]
Gunners
  Shakujima  [arrow resist 4]
  Akaga      [Rapid shot 3]
  Oshiya     [Rapid shot 3] kairo mail
  Shishi     [strategy 4]
Cavalry
  Shalala    [Horse resist 4]
  Mogami     [Attack up 3]
  Bearington [strategy 5]
```

Anyone have a winning strategy?

Comment: I don't think its beatable, eventually you get stuck due to the enemy becoming too strong to kill within 3 days.  the level 100 reward is the last special one you'll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, the training ground is endless and no matter what you do you will eventually run into an army that you cannot defeat within 3 turns, thus always ending with a draw.  Other than gold, the last special item you will receive from it is the Kario Mail at level 100.

Having said that, I believe I have found the optimal configuration for my army to use in the training grounds:

Infantry:

- Bearington [Strategy 5] (front) Kairo armor
- Inuzuka [Projectile Proof] (front)
- Inuzuka#2 [Projectile Proof] (front) <- I cloned her for my new game+

Archery:

- Kimura [Strategy 4] (middle)

Gunners:

- Shishi [Strategy 4] (front) - Rifle
- Kongo [Attack Up 4] (front) - Rifle (she has the highest marksmanship out of any ninja with the Attack Up skill).  I'd prefer to bring another rapid shot ninja but Fukuyo's marks is just TERRIBAD.
- Shakuji [Arrow Resist 4] (front) - Rifle
- Oshiya [Rapid Shot 3] (middle) - Kairo Mail & Flame Cannon + Toad
- Akagawa [Rapid Shot 3] (back) - Flame Cannon + White Horse
- Dorifu [Rapid Shot 3] (back) - Flame Cannon + White Horse

Calvary:

- Asaryu [Strategy 4] (middle)
- Chimpan Z [Horse Resist 5] (middle)

The reasoning behind this setup:

1. Projectile proof front line in the infantry guarentees that my 3 ninjas there will survive all 3 rounds, and they can do a lot of damage with their Super Ninjato.  Any other ninja up front will die by round 2 due to gun damage.  The rest of the foot soldiers are there purely to soak up any remaining damage so nothing can get to my gunners.  Outside of that, infantry don't do nearly enough damage to be worth any more ninjas (especially since the ninja dog almost always dies after 1 round).
2. Kimura has great marksmanship and Strategy 4, so he can be an archer.  I always target opposing archers every round so my gunners can do more damage.
3. The gunners do the most damage in the game, so I will bring along as many as I can.  The reason for the staggering is 2 fold:

   - I use rifles up front as they shoot multiple times to 'open up' gaps in the opposing army.
   - This allows my rapid fire flame cannons to get in the middle before their AOE explosions go off for maximum damage.
4. The whole point of the calvary is to soak up the opponent's calvary and to do whatever remaining damage they can do, so having the highest remaining strategy and highest calvary resist helps in that regard.

Using this strategy you will be able to proceed past level 145, but again, eventually you'll be stuck at some point.

Final note, it might be worth it to shift bearington to gunners just for the additional 5% damage.  I haven't tried it since Shishi has such high marksmanship.